# POST fetch problem in React component using FormData

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have a React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import UserPhoto from '../../images/Dorothy.jpg';
import { useState } from 'react';
import PostVideoIcon from '../icons/post/PostVideoIcon';
import PostImageIcon from '../icons/post/PostImageIcon';
import PostPhotoIcon from '../icons/post/PostPhotoIcon';
import PostLinkIcon from '../icons/post/PostLinkIcon';
import PostIconWrapper from '../PostIconWrapper/PostIconWrapper';

const NewsAddPost = () => {
    const placeholder = 'What’s on your mind, Dorothy?';
    const [text, setText] = useState(placeholder);
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);


    const handleSendClick = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const date = new Date().toISOString();
        const author = 'Dorothy Kovalsky Parker'; // ! temporary hardcode
        const content = document.querySelector("#content").textContent;

        console.log(date + ' ' + author + ' ' + content);

        formData.append("date", date);
        formData.append("author", author);
        formData.append("content", content);

        try {
            fetch('http://localhost:5000/posts', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };


    return (
        <div className='flex flex-col gap-[15px] p-[15px] bg-[#fff] rounded-[15px] shadow-componentshadow'>
            <div className='flex gap-[10px] items-center'>
                <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${UserPhoto})` }}
                    className='h-[40px] w-[40px] rounded-full relative bg-center bg-cover bg-no-repeat' ></div>
                <div contentEditable="true"
                    name='content'
                    id='content'
                    placeholder={text ? text : placeholder}
                    onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
                    onBlur={() => { setIsFocused(false); setText(text.trim() ? text.trim() : placeholder) }}
                    suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
                    onInput={e => setText(e.currentTarget.innerText)}
                    className='bg-colorExtraLightGray w-[100%] rounded-[10px] p-[8px] text-colorTextLightGray resize-none hover:bg-colorLightGray hover:cursor-pointer focus:hover:bg-white focus:bg-white focus:cursor-auto focus:outline-colorExtraLightGray focus:text-colorTextBlack'>
                </div>
            </div>
            {(text.trim() !== placeholder || isFocused) ?
                <div className='flex gap-[10px] items-center justify-between'>
                    <div className='flex items-center gap-[10px]'>
                        <PostIconWrapper><PostVideoIcon /></PostIconWrapper>
                        <PostIconWrapper><PostImageIcon /></PostIconWrapper>
                        <PostIconWrapper><PostPhotoIcon /></PostIconWrapper>
                        <PostIconWrapper><PostLinkIcon /></PostIconWrapper>
                    </div>
                    <button className="bg-accent py-[12px] border border-accent px-[15px] rounded-[10px] text-[#fff]  gap-[10px] whitespace-nowrap hover:bg-opacity-90"
                        onClick={handleSendClick}>
                        Publish
                    </button>
                </div>
                : <></>
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default NewsAddPost;
```

trying to send request and getting 500 responce code, but backend is fine:
[using postman all works fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDFLv.jpg)

`console.log(date + ' ' + author + ' ' + content);`
returns: **"2024-02-29T14:18:31.178Z Dorothy Kovalsky Parker fsd fs sdf sdff"** - all fields value is ok.

On backend console i see the following error:

> Error: Post validation failed: content: Path `content` is required., date: Path `date` is required., author: Path `author` is required. And all fields value: undefined.

What did i miss?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want to send JSON?

Comment: When you use Postman, what is the `Content-Type` header that you send to your API? Does it expect a `multipart/form-data` or a `application/json`?

Comment: @Dave Newton you are right, I should send JSON

Comment: @moonstar-x i got it, it's JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
const data = {
  date,
  author,
  content,
}
fetch('http://localhost:5000/posts', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```

Here `Content-Type` is important, if your app accepts json, then the above code is valid.

You can refer to the mdn docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: oh, thanks!

>Content-Type is important

true!